# exchange database quota limits

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, quota

Hello I am having issues creating a script and am hoping that someone can help!

I need a script that will set the mailbox database quota default limits and then for all users that are set to `usedatabasequotadefaults:$false` it will take the mailbox statistics totalitemsize and add 250mb to create a custom quota.

I have been trying the below but cannot get it to work.

Also a way to test this on an individual user before the whole database would be great

```
$usrs = (Get-Mailbox -Database "Server1\MailboxDatabase1") 
$dbconfig = (Get-MailboxDatabase) 
foreach ($i in $usrs){
    $MbStats = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $i)
    if ($MbStats.totalItemSize.value.tomb()) -gt $dbconfig.IssueWarningQuota){
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $i -UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults:$False -IssueWarningQuota $(($MbStats.TotalItemSize.Value.tomb())+250)
    }

}
```

Comment: First issue i see is `$dbconfig`. How many databases do you have? `$dbconfig = (Get-MailboxDatabase) ` would be an array of databases which would make `-gt $dbconfig.IssueWarningQuota` not work properly. Should it not just be `$dbconfig = Get-MailboxDatabase "Server1\MailboxDatabase1"`

Comment: Change `$usrs = get-mailbox username` to test one mailbox

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script now mostly works but the issue I have is with the following $(($MbStats.TotalItemSize.Value.tomb())+250)     }  }

Comment: It only sets the warning quota to 250mb and not to the current mailbox totalitemsize plus 250mb?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, use `$usrs = Get-Mailbox userPrincipalName` (userPrincipalName instead of username to account for multidomain)

Use the `-Whatif` parameter to test your script Set-Mailbox -Whatif .....

Other suggestions:

- You can write your script to be much more descriptive in the variable names.  This will clarify what they are to you and anyone you ask to look over your script.
- `$usrs` might be better written as `$Mailboxes` since you are working on Mailboxes not users.
- foreach loop becomes:  `foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {...}`
- `$dbconfig = Get-MailboxDatabase` -- this command loads all exchange mailbox databases into memory as a collection of objects stored in $dbconfig, then you do nothing with it.

Out of curiosity, why automatically raise the warning quota instead of removing them?

Edit:

If you need filters, the Where-Object cmdlet is your friend:

To list mailboxes that do not use default quota and set them to 250:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Database "Server1\MailboxDatabase1"
$Mailboxes = $Mailboxes | Where-Object -Property UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults -eq $False
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    Set-Mailbox $Mailbox -IssueWarningQuota 250000
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just compared to the queston.  I see more what it is asking now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script now mostly works but the issue I have is with the following $(($MbStats.TotalItemSize.Value.tomb())+250) } }

Comment: It only sets the warning quota to 250mb and not to the current mailbox totalitemsize plus 250mb?